# Error utilizando split dentro de lapply en R. ¿Cómo solucionarlo?

Tags: r, funciones, programación-funcional

Utilizando un poco de mezcla base R con `tidyverse`, aplico `split` para obtener las medias de las variables numéricas de la base mtcars incluida en R: (No adjunto resultado porque es el esperado)

```
Filter(is.numeric, mtcars) %>% 
    split(.$cyl) %>%
    lapply(., function(x) colMeans(x))
```

Ahora bien, cuando intento aplicar split directamente dentro de `lapply`, me marca error:

```
Filter(is.numeric, mtcars) %>%
    lapply(split(., cyl), function(x) colMeans(x))

Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'split(., cyl)' is not a function, character or symbol
```

He intentado diversas combinaciones dentro de `split` y el error siempre es el mismo y honestamente no lo entiendo ya que, como se sabe, el llamado a la función dentro de `lapply` es el segundo argumento y no el primero. 
Cualquier orientación será muy apreciada.

Comment: Creo que el problema es que tanto `lapply` como `%>%` se basan en evaluación no estándar, entonces `FUN=` en algún lugar recibe el `.`  de `%>%` como argumento, aunque uno no lo especifique. Por ejemplo: `lapply(split(Filter(is.numeric, mtcars), mtcars$cyl), colMeans)` funciona, pero `Filter(is.numeric, mtcars) %>% 
  lapply(X= split(., .$cyl), FUN = function(x) colMeans (x))` marca que sobra un punto. En otras variantes siempre da un error relacionado con que sobra un argumento, creo que la tubería está insertando el `.` en los argumentos adicionales de `lapply` (los famosos `...`)

Comment: Pregunta ingenua: ¿Por qué no `mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, mean)`.

Comment: @mpaladino Como comenté en la publicación, básicamente estaba jugando a mezclar base R con tidyverse y de ahí me surgió la duda. Conforme avanzo en mis lecturas de programación funcional, trato de explorar diversas soluciones para un mismo problema. Saludos :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando originalmente haces `lapply(., function(x) colMeans(x))` estás indicando que la salida de la función anterior se incorpore al primer parámetro de `lapply` que por otro lado es el comportamiento por defecto del `pipe`, por lo que permíteme simplificar tu código al mínimo, para que sea más sencillo de ver el problema:

```
Filter(is.numeric, mtcars) %>% 
    split(.$cyl) %>%
    lapply(colMeans)
```

Por otro lado `mtcars` son únicamente variables numéricas, así que a efectos didácticos quitaremos el `Filter(is.numeric, mtcars)`. Con todo lo anterior, el nuevo código que estás intentando sería:

```
mtcars %>%
    lapply(split(., cyl), colMeans)

Error in split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) : 
  object 'cyl' not found
```

Lo que nos dice el error, es que R no puede ubicar el objeto `cyl` (además, tienes un problema con el uso del `pipe` pero lo voy a dejar para el final). Por ahora voy a transformar el pipe en una invocación normal de lo que estarías buscando hacer, para entenderlo mejor:

```
lapply(split(mtcars, cyl), 
       colMeans
)

Error in split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) : 
  object 'cyl' not found
```

Mismo error, el problema ahora, claramente lo tenemos en `split(mtcars, cyl)`, ¿Que es lo que ocurre? mpaladino ya te lo adelantó en los comentarios, tiene que ver con la mezcla de distintos tipos de evaluación. En R existen dos formas de evaluar una expresión,

- Evaluación estándar (EE)
- Evaluación No estándar (ENE)

`dplyr` hace un uso intensivo de la **ENE** pero rutinas base como `split()` usan **EE**.

Veamos como funciona una **EE** en el caso de `split()` y muchas otras funciones. Para hacer un split por cilindro, normalmente haríamos esto:

```
split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
```

Sin embargo, si intentamos algo "esotérico", al menos en esta instancia como ser `split(mtcars, cyl)`  nos dará error. Lo que ocurre es que los parámetros en el caso de `split()` se evalúan de forma estándar, es además la forma en que son evaluados en la mayoría de los lenguajes. La forma estándar evalúa la existencia de las variables pasadas por parámetros en el entorno desde dónde invocamos la función, es decir al invocar la función debemos pasar una referencia a un objeto que ya exista y además que sea válido para la operación que se desea hacer. De ahí, que **tu problema es esta llamada: `split(mtcars, cyl)` ya que `cyl` no existe en el entorno de evaluación**. Lo que deberías hacer en este caso es algo así:

```
lapply(mtcars, 
       split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl), 
       colMeans)
```

#### ¿Y.. cual es la magia que tiene `dplyr` que me permite escribir mucho menos?

Por ejemplo, ¿que es esto?

```
filter(mtcars, cyl == 8 & mpg > 15)
```

Atención: no confundas `filter` de `dplyr` con `Filter`. En este caso `filter()` nos "filtra" aquellas autos con 8 cilindros y más de 15 millas por galón. ¿Pero, en que lugar hemos definido `cyl` o `mpg`? ¿No es un caso parecido al anterior? ¿Por que ahora si funciona? Bueno, esta es la magia de la evaluación NO estándar, es algo muy poderoso que permiten poquísimos lenguajes, R es uno de ellos. Básicamente puedes escribir funciones que evalúen los parámetros de una forma distinta a la normal, en el ejemplo de `filter()`, la función evalúa `cyl == 8 & mpg > 15` dentro del entorno de `mtcars`, de ahí que ahora sí `cyl` y `mpg` existan. No quiero complicarte demasiado la vida, pero te quería dejar un ejemplo, de como sería una versión de `split()` pero con **ENE**, verás que la implementación es bastante sencilla:

```
my_split <- function(x, condition) {
    condition_call <- substitute(condition)
    env <- list2env(x, parent = parent.frame())
    r <- eval(condition_call, env)
    split(x, r)
}
```

Lo fundamental es `r <- eval(condition_call, env)`, `r` será nuestro `mtcars$cyl` gracias a que el parámetro `condition` es evaluado en un entorno ya creado, el cual ya contiene el objeto `x` (`mtcars`). Y ahora podemos hacer tranquilamente: `my_split(mycars, cyl)`.

#### Finalmente

El otro problema más simple, lo tienes en el uso del `pipe`, veamos

```
mtcars %>%
    lapply(split(., cyl), colMeans)
```

En realidad estarías haciendo esto:

```
lapply(mtcars, split(., cyl), colMeans)
```

El `pipe` establece como primer parámetro siempre el retorno de la función anterior, por lo que nos mueve `split(., cyl)` al lugar de `FUN` que debiera ser `colMeans`. Por más que arregles la llamada a `split()` este último problema persistirá, como estas en un `pipe`, el `split()` debiera ejecutarse antes que el `lapply` ya que la salida del primero, será la entrada del segundo. Tu primer código es el válido:

```
Filter(is.numeric, mtcars) %>% 
    split(.$cyl) %>%
    lapply(colMeans)
```

Todo esto, esta mucho mejor explicado por  Hadley Wickham en el capítulo correspondiente en [advance R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html), o en [Tidy evaluation](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/)

Comment: Aunque intuía correctamente que iba por el lado de la ENE, me dejaste, como siempre, sorprendido con tu respuesta. Muchas gracias :D